# Is the word ''analyse'' a noun or a verb? A countable noun or an uncountable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

As we know, the word *analysis* is a noun, and can be used as both a countable noun and an uncountable noun; the word *analyze* is a verb. As I have known this word *analyse* can be used as a verb, but for its another use as a noun, I have a blurry understanding.

Can it be used as a noun, and if so, as a countable noun or an uncountable noun？

Comment: Can you give an example of how it could be used as a noun? I can't think of one. Maybe you're thinking of _analysis._

Comment: A dictionary can tell you these things

Comment: The plural form of the word analysis is analyse. All that I know about this word analyse is that it can be used as a verb. But I do not know whether it can be used as a noun. If yes, can it be a countable noun or an uncountable noun?

Comment: I cannot think of an example for the word ananlyse when used as a noun.

Comment: @MikeHarris: Well, in French the word for analysis is "analyse", and Google Books shows some examples of people using "the analyse" as a noun in English to mean "the analysis". But I would think of this as a error due to interference from knowledge of another language.

Comment: JoyJo, the plural of analysis is [_analyses_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analyses) (note the final "s"). It is also the plural for the French singular that @sumelic mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know why you’re confused.

1. The **plural** of the noun *analysis* /əˈnæləsɪs/ is *analyses* /əˈnæləsiːz/. Since the noun has a plural form, it is a count noun not an uncountable one.
2. The **singular** of the verb *analyse* /ˈænəˌlaɪz/ is ***also*** spelled  *analyses* — but now that spelling is suddenly pronounced /ˈænəˌlaɪzəz/, which is quite different from the plural noun’s pronunciation.

You may spell the verbs *analyze* and *analyzes* if you wish; it changes nothing in the pronunciation. Just make sure to be consistent and stick to one or the other.

It’s quite normal in English to have a noun and verb spelled the same way but pronounced differently.

The OED attests that historically the noun *analyse* **did** once upon a time exist in English, but says that that usage is now considered obsolete today. In our day, *analyse* “can” only be a verb in new writing, never a noun. Sometimes the OED is a bit overzealous with obsolescing words that you can still find in rare usage, but I’d advise against using this one if I were you.

Comment: So in English, the word _analyse_ is just a verb, and cannot be used as a noun. The word _analyses_ is the plural of the noun _analysis_ and singular of the verb _analyse_. Is that right?

Comment: @JoyJo In today's English, yes, you are correct. However, the OED attests that historically the noun *ˈanalyse* **did** once upon a time exist in English, but says that that is now obsolete today.

Comment: Thank you so much for your perfect answer. I have confused about these words for a long time and the answers vary from person to person. Your answer just cleared my confusion.

Comment: This answer should probably be edited to clarify that "analyze" is American (etc.) English and "analyse" is British (etc.) English. Americans don't write "analyse", and Brits don't write "analyze". But we both write "analysis" (and its plural "analyses"). See also: *paralyse* vs. *paralyze* vs. *paralysis*; and presumably other technical terms such as *autolysis* and *catalysis*.

Comment: @Quux, can you confirm that the `-yse`/`-yze` split is *not* the same as the `-ise`/`-ize` split (where US always prefers `-ize`, and Britain accepts either, and notably Oxford Dictionaries prefers `-ize`)?  Thanks.

Comment: @Toby I can do that. OED uses *-ize* for words of Greek origin where the Greek used the letter zeta in a *-zein* suffix. *Analysis* comes ultimately from  *ἀνάλυσις* which uses sigma and so the *-yse* spelling is standard. AmE appears to have standardised on *-ize* everywhere, and this has transferred to *-yze* for this verb.

Comment: Is the term *singular verb* correctly used here? Should not it rather read *verb not in 3rd person singular*? The plural verb *analyse* is written the same.